# is it possible to read local files contents using liquid shopify and load its contents into the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, liquid, template-engine

I am testing our web application which was built using Liquid Shopify and Ruby on Rails. I found a mail template page in the admin panel that can by customized using liquid template engine  `{{shop.name}}` . Now i am wondering if i can take that beyond that. Does liquid shopify support to read local file or even system file contents and load its contents into the page? or maybe invoke some classes and methods that trigger code execution on the server?

how can below code be used to read local system/config file

`template = Liquid::Template.parse(File.read("template.liquid"))`

Answer (score 0):

If you parse a Liquid file in your App, you would fill in values for things like {{shop.name}} using Drops. The Documentation on using Liquid is pretty clear about how to use Liquid in your own Apps.

Comment: My concern is about security testing by checking the possibilty of being able to load and render a system file like etc/passwd on the page. Is that possible in liquid?

Comment: It is your App. You decide what files to read. That is not something the client controls. Hence Liquid is secure. The whole reason Liquid exists was to eliminate the template security flaws of so many old templating libraries where the template was under client control.

Comment: Thank you for replying.. but is that possible in liquid? If yes.. please tell me what classes and methods can be used to load and render files such as application.rb / config.ru

Comment: As i know liquid is safe and does not allow reading files from outside webroot dir and it does not allow executing systems commands such as ls

Comment: You architect your App such that YOU can read files, but your customers cannot access data other than what the templates allow.

Comment: Liquid is nice for many uses. CMS type sites are great with it. A lot of artistic freedom there. You can also return Liquid to Shopify in App Proxy calls, allowing theme designers to use your custom Liquid to show data present only in your App as opposed to in Shopify itself.